# Non static members as default parameters in C++

Tags: c++, default-value, non-static

I'm refactoring a large amount of code where I have to add an extra parameter to a number of functions, which will always have a value of a member of that object.  Something like

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   CMyObject A,B;

   void MyFunc(CMyObject &Object);
   // used to be void MyFunc();
};
```

Now, I'd actually like it to read

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   CMyObject A,B;

   void MyFunc(CMyObject &Object = A);
};
```

But I'm not allowed to have a default parameter that is a non-static member.  I've read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124921/static-binding-of-default-parameter) which suggest this isn't possible, but I'm wondering if there is any reasonable workaround.  Reason being that 95% of the time the default parameter will be used, and thus using a default parameter would hugely reduce the amount of code I have to change.  My best solution so far is something like this;

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   CMyObject A,B;

   void MyFunc(BOOL IsA = TRUE);
};

void MyClass::MyFunc(BOOL IsA)
{
    CMyObject &Object = A;
    if (!IsA)
        Object = &B;
}
```

This is less than elgant, but is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?

**Edit:** FWIW, the reason for the extra parameter is to externalize some state related members from the object in question to aid multi-threading.

Comment: If it has a data member, by definition it is not stateless.

Comment: Fair point Neil, text edited.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about :

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   CMyObject A,B;

   void MyFunc()
   { 
     MyFunc(A); 
   }
   void MyFunc(CMyObject &Object);
};
```

?

Comment: Thanks Benoit, i knew there had to be a better way.  Staring at the screen too long.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that overloads aren't allowed in C# and Java, and this is the way to compensate. So I guess i haven't invented anything :-)

Comment: I think you mean default parameters aren't allowed in C# and Java - they certainly allow overloads (and default parameters are apparently in C# 4.0)

Comment: I think the only problem with this would be if the default parameter A changes and we have to pass, let's say, C. Then either you've to update A before calling any MyFunc() or call MyFunc(C) everywhere instead of MyFunc()

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyObject A,B;

   void MyFunc(MyObject MyClass::*myObject = &MyClass::A) {
       MyObject& obj = *(this->*myObject);
   }
};
```

This makes it even impossible to pass in an MyObject member from another MyClass instance. Your three valid options to call MyFunc are `.MyFunc()`, `.MyFunc(&MyClass::A)` and `.MyFunc(&MyClass::B)`